# I cannot run a Spring Cloud Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have an example of Spring Cloud based Java Application, but it uses the company customized Spring API to run.

Now Application Runner is:

```java
package org.example.demo.server;

import com.hundsun.jrescloud.common.boot.CloudApplication;
import com.hundsun.jrescloud.common.boot.CloudBootstrap;

@CloudApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CloudBootstrap.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Because I'm using JDK 17, the app started with some errors and which were fixed by add `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED` to **VM Options** to solve `Unable to make field public static final boolean com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY accessible: module java.management does not "exports com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver" to unnamed module @3590fc5b`.

But after add these vm options, now it reports (the reason appears at the end):
`Caused by java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public static final boolean com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY accessible: module java.management does not "exports com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver" to unnamed module @3590fc5b`.
Therefore I'm wondering how to solve this problem.

The problem is too weird to find a solution, I have searched it on some search engines with no solution.

The whole report is

```
2022-07-14 21:57:21.204 |-ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication [] -| Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter]: Factory method 'mbeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to init remote service reference at filed DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY in class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public static final boolean com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY accessible: module java.management does not "exports com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver" to unnamed module @3590fc5b
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1082) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1071) [spring-boot-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at com.hundsun.jrescloud.common.boot.CloudBootstrap.run(CloudBootstrap.java:69) [jrescloud-common-2.0.39.jar:2.0.39]
    at com.hundsun.jrescloud.common.boot.CloudBootstrap.run(CloudBootstrap.java:50) [jrescloud-common-2.0.39.jar:2.0.39]
    at org.example.demo.server.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter]: Factory method 'mbeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to init remote service reference at filed DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY in class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public static final boolean com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY accessible: module java.management does not "exports com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver" to unnamed module @3590fc5b
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to init remote service reference at filed DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY in class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public static final boolean com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY accessible: module java.management does not "exports com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver" to unnamed module @3590fc5b
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter(JmxAutoConfiguration.java:82) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b.CGLIB$mbeanExporter$2(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4ed9fd1a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b.mbeanExporter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to init remote service reference at filed DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY in class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public static final boolean com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY accessible: module java.management does not "exports com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver" to unnamed module @3590fc5b
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.config.spring.AnnotationBean.postProcessBeforeInitialization(AnnotationBean.java:439) ~[jrescloud-rpc-def-2.0.39.jar:2.0.39]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1622) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter(JmxAutoConfiguration.java:82) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b.CGLIB$mbeanExporter$2(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4ed9fd1a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b.mbeanExporter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field public static final boolean com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.DEFAULT_FAIR_LOCK_POLICY accessible: module java.management does not "exports com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver" to unnamed module @3590fc5b
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.config.spring.AnnotationBean.postProcessBeforeInitialization(AnnotationBean.java:419) ~[jrescloud-rpc-def-2.0.39.jar:2.0.39]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1622) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter(JmxAutoConfiguration.java:82) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b.CGLIB$mbeanExporter$2(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4ed9fd1a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f4250b.mbeanExporter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.22.RELEASE.jar:1.5.22.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Which Spring Boot version it uses? If it doesn't use 2.7 it doesn't support Java17 (officially). This looks like an old version using Spring 4.3 which doesn't support Java17.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok fine, then problem solved, the spring version is still 4.x

Comment: The reflection is happing in dubbo, not framework
`at com.alibaba.dubbo.config.spring.AnnotationBean.postProcessBeforeInitialization(AnnotationBean.java:419) ~[jrescloud-rpc-def-2.0.39.jar:2.0.39]`

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue and was able to work around it by adding the following two JVM args:

```
--add-opens=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED
```